# Replace multiple occurences of a comment with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace multiple occurences of comment and try like below

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/fnRcL/391/)

Code:

```
var str = '<!--#test--><!--#test1-->'
str = str.replace('<!--/g', '').replace('-->/g', '');
alert(str)
```

Comment: Can you Provide some test case like what is data set and what wanna pull from that data source etc etc .

Comment: by seeing your reputation it doesn't seems that you will post like this buddy... can you elaborate the question

Comment: Please post the code. You seem to violate the terms of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use a string instead of a regular expression. For example, this works.

```
var str = '<!--#test-->'
str = str.replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');
alert(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain regex commands need to be inside `//`.
Also, use the 
 *Disjunction; Alternative* `|` (*pipe character*)

```
str = str.replace(/<!--|-->/g, ''); // #test#test1
```